# Using style defined in merged dictionary from another merged dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Below you can see how I am trying to segregate styles by merging dictionaries (I'm skipping namespaces for the sake of cleanliness)

*App.xaml*:

```
<Application.Resources>       
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Style/HeaderStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

*Colors.xaml*:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DarkTextForeground" Color="#7471b9"/>
```

*HeaderStyle.xaml*:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DarkTextForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

During compilation I get a following error:

> Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key DarkTextForeground

To make It work we have to merge *Colors.xaml* inside *HeaderStyle.xaml* like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Style x:Key="HeaderTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DarkTextForeground}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

Can anyone explain to me, why I have to reference *Colors.xaml* in *HeaderStyle.xaml*?
 Can't I just reference styles defined in different merged dictionary?
I assume that *Colors.xaml* is loaded before *HeaderStyle.xaml* so it should be visible for dictionaries defined later.

Comment: You are talking about Visual Studio design time right? The actual project will build/run ok though right? I was able to get this to work in design time by referencing the MergedDictionaries in the App.xaml `Application.Resources`

Comment: @BrockHensley I'm bit confused because in example without `MergedDictionary` inside HeaderTyle.xaml: in VS Design View everything is ok (I can see Text with color), I can even Build Project with success, but when I try to run it I get XamlParseException: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key DarkTextForeground.

Comment: +1 for what @Romasz said. Exactly what happened to me.

Comment: Static resources are resolved at compile time by looking in that ResourceDictionary and any resource dictionaries within its MergedDictionaries only. It does try to walk up to a parent and check sibling dictionaries. I don't even think the RD has a pointer to the "parent" dictionary.

Comment: Oops I meant to say "It _doesn't_ try to walk up". Anyway the question seems answer but I'll amend my comment anyway just in case someone reads it at a later time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a response to [my question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/2be9a5f6-5313-448d-a9d9-296bac42215e/using-style-defined-in-merged-dictionary-from-another-merged-dictionary?forum=wpdevelop) from Erick Fleck at msdn forums:

> *In your first example each file is parsed independently and then added to the merged dictionary so they don't know anything about each other...similarly, the XAML in a merged dictionary cannot reference names in the 'parent' ResourceDictionary.  In other words, you should think of a MergedDictionaries as a one-way reference.*

It's the way It works I guess...