# MergedDictionaries can not be referenced from App.xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

My styles are separated in separate files for better organization and readability. All files are referenced in my App.xaml. Some styles are `BasedOn` other styles, so I have placed them in the proper order so that the inherited styles are loaded before the dependent ones. However, I am still getting the following error on my XAML views that reference a font style, for example...`Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SourceSansPro-Light`.

Can someone enlighten me on why this Name/Key cannot be found? Here's  the relevant code.

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/Styles/StyleResources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/Styles/InputStyles.xaml" />                
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

StyleResources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBoxBackgroundBrush" Color="White"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>

<FontFamily x:Key="SourceSansPro-Light">../../Assets/Fonts/SourceSansPro-Light.otf#Source Sans      Pro</FontFamily>

<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SourceSansPro-Semibold}" />
</Style>
```

InputStyles.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="SecondaryTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}">
   <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SourceSansPro-Light}"/>
</Style>
```

HomePage.xaml (where style, SourceSansPro-Light, is being called in this view)

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="InfoBodyTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SourceSansPro-Light}"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Can you try to run without `SourceSansPro-light` in `InputStyles.xaml`?

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21646544/using-style-defined-in-merged-dictionary-from-another-merged-dictionary?rq=1) has the answer you're looking for. You can't use `SourceSansPro-Light` in InputStyles.xaml because InputStyles.xaml is parsed independently from StyleResources.xaml. You'd have to merge StyleResources.xaml into InputStyles.xaml.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, if you post your comment as answer, I'll accept it since it was specific to  my issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF64CCEF"/>        
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>       
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource FontFamilyResource}"/>                     
</Style>

<FontFamily x:Key="FontFamilyResource">/ApplicationName(SolutionName);component/Resources/Fonts/#Vladimir Script</FontFamily>
```